# Android button state files

Tags: android, state, drawable

The docs say to put XML state files for buttons in "the" "drawable" folder - which one of at least three?! (Putting it in res/drawable gives an out of sync filesystem error and putting it in each of the drawable-*dpi where * is l, m, h is an error too.)

Comment: My bad, didn't get the XML part. I'll look in to it.

Comment: As far as I know, you can delete those three drawable-*dpi folders and use just one drawable.

Comment: @MEGA: No worries. I propose `drawable-nodpi` for XML files. I hate the docs for their ambiguity. Rock on Apple.

Comment: You raise a good question, in my opinion. I did not find a good answer for it in their documentation, it is not updated yet (they still use `drawable` as reference). Give them some time to update.

Answer (score 1):

res/drawable is ok and default.

The "fs out of sync" is probably from your IDE when you put the files e.g. via command line or into the folder. IDEs usually try to remember the state of files and report external changes this way. Try issuing a "refresh" command in the IDE.

res/drawable is a fallback that is taken if you do not provide more specific images in res/drawable-*dpi or also some orientation counterparts.

Have a look at the docs: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

drawable-nodpi is a special directory for files you don't want scaled, which makes no sense at all for buttons, as you want buttons to scale according to screen size/dpi.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Since the file is an XML file scaling is irrelevant. I've taken care of the button scaling separately (by introducing button images). There is no harm in putting my selector XML in -nodpi then.............? o/w Can you clarify this by giving an example of when you would use the special meaning of -nodpi if not here?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood you partially then. I'd put (have put) the xml into res/drawable/ as this is the fallback directory (i.e. this is where the system looks by default, if nothing else is provided).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this again. My original reason for posting the question was not the file system error from Eclipse, but that the drawable was being missed entirely by Java when I placed it in res/drawable. For some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `res/drawable` for your XML state list drawables. If you get the "out of sync filesystem" error just refresh the Eclipse project (select it in the projects pane and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>).

XML state lists are (in most cases) not DPI-independent. However, their content will not change across different DPI environments. Basically, this means that if you reference a raw drawable called, for example, `@drawable/btn_pressed`, from within a state list, Android will look for the appropriate file for that drawable, according to the environment  (`drawable-*dpi/btn_pressed.png`).

As you can see, although the state list is the same on LDPI, MDPI and HDPI, the drawables referenced within it could change.

Answer (score -2):

I propose `drawable-nodpi` because it works.

However this is not made obvious in the docs when it needs to be.

**How to make something trivial complicated? Make it ambiguous.**

Comment: That's a bad answer. Also, writing "Rock on Apple" in a comment on an Android question makes you look... stupid.

Comment: -nodpi is a special qualifier with special meaning.

Comment: Another example: "(Level-list) A Drawable that manages a number of alternate Drawables, each assigned a maximum numerical value. Setting the level value of the drawable with setLevel() loads **the** drawable resource in the level list that has **a** android:maxLevel value greater than or equal to the value passed to the method." BUT there can be more than one drawable resource with a maxLevel greater than the passed value! I find this kind of ambiguity very unhelpful.

Comment: most probably it picks the one with the lowest `maxLevel` greater than the value passed to `setLevel()`. If there are more than one with the same `maxLevel`, it probably picks the first one in the XML, but you probably shouldn't do that anyway. Also, you can test that very easily. And yes, it is pretty well known that Android documentation is not really up to par (they acknowledged it themselves), and they are working on it. Again, no use in bashing, or "Rock on Apple" fanboyism.

Comment: @Felix: It *probably* does, yes.